# Compilation error related to template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class IOperation
    {
        public:
        virtual void Invoke(T data) = 0;
    };

template<typename T>
class ReverseStringOperation: public IOperation<T>
{
    public:
    void Invoke(T data)override{

        std::cout<<"Reversed data :";
        //std::cout<<"Reversed data :"<< std::reverse(std::begin(data),std::end(data));

    }

};


   template<typename T>
   class Pipeline : public IOperation<T>
    {
        std::vector<IOperation<T>> operations{}; 
       
       public:
       Pipeline(){}
        // add operation at the end of the pipeline
        void Register(IOperation<T>& operation)
        {
            operations.push_back(operation);
        }

        // invoke every operations
        void Invoke(T data) override
        {
            
            for (auto& operation : operations)
            {
                operation.Invoke(data);
                
            }
                        
            
        }
    };

int main(){

ReverseStringOperation<std::string> rObj;
std::string str = "Hello";

Pipeline<std::string> *pipeline = new Pipeline<std::string>();

pipeline->Register(rObj);
//pipeline->Invoke(str);
    
    delete pipeline;
    return 0;
}
```

Hi, I am trying to create a simple pipeline pattern using templates. I am getting compile time error: Template argument deduction when this call --- **[pipeline->Register(rObj);]** is made from main. This operation of **IOperation& operation= rObj** is failing to instantiate the **IOperation**. How can i fix this error ?

Error Log:

```
Starting build...
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g -std=c++20 "G:\Projects\Cpp Practice\Pipeline\main.cpp" -o "G:\Projects\Cpp Practice\Pipeline\main.exe"
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/ext/alloc_traits.h:34,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/basic_string.h:40,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/string:53,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/ios:42,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/ostream:38,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from G:\Projects\Cpp Practice\Pipeline\main.cpp:1:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/alloc_traits.h: In instantiation of 'static constexpr void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::construct(allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Args = {const IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&}; _Tp = IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; allocator_type = std::allocator<IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1281:30:   required from 'constexpr void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; value_type = IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]'
G:\Projects\Cpp Practice\Pipeline\main.cpp:35:33:   required from 'void Pipeline<T>::Register(IOperation<T>&) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
G:\Projects\Cpp Practice\Pipeline\main.cpp:59:19:   required from here
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/alloc_traits.h:518:28: error: no matching function for call to 'construct_at(IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*&, const IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)'
  518 |           std::construct_at(__p, std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/char_traits.h:46,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/ios:40:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_construct.h:94:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp, class ... _Args> constexpr decltype (::new(void*(0)) _Tp) std::construct_at(_Tp*, _Args&& ...)'
   94 |     construct_at(_Tp* __location, _Args&&... __args)
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_construct.h:94:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_construct.h: In substitution of 'template<class _Tp, class ... _Args> constexpr decltype (::new(void*(0)) _Tp) std::construct_at(_Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Args = {const IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&}]':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/alloc_traits.h:518:21:   required from 'static constexpr void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::construct(allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Args = {const IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&}; _Tp = IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; allocator_type = std::allocator<IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1281:30:   required from 'constexpr void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; value_type = IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]'
G:\Projects\Cpp Practice\Pipeline\main.cpp:35:33:   required from 'void Pipeline<T>::Register(IOperation<T>&) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
G:\Projects\Cpp Practice\Pipeline\main.cpp:59:19:   required from here
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_construct.h:96:17: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >'
   96 |     -> decltype(::new((void*)0) _Tp(std::declval<_Args>()...))
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
G:\Projects\Cpp Practice\Pipeline\main.cpp:5:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >':
    5 | class IOperation
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
G:\Projects\Cpp Practice\Pipeline\main.cpp:8:22: note:     'void IOperation<T>::Invoke(T) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
    8 |         virtual void Invoke(T data) = 0;
      |                      ^~~~~~
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/vector:63,
                 from G:\Projects\Cpp Practice\Pipeline\main.cpp:2:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h: In instantiation of 'constexpr bool std::__check_constructible() [with _ValueType = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Tp = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&&]':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:182:4:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = move_iterator<IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*>; _ForwardIterator = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:372:37:   required from 'constexpr _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = move_iterator<IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*>; _ForwardIterator = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*; _Tp = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:397:2:   required from 'constexpr _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Allocator&) [with _InputIterator = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*; _ForwardIterator = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*; _Allocator = allocator<IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/vector.tcc:487:3:   required from 'constexpr void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_realloc_insert(iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&}; _Tp = IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; iterator = std::vector<IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >::iterator]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1287:21:   required from 'constexpr void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; value_type = IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]'
G:\Projects\Cpp Practice\Pipeline\main.cpp:35:33:   required from 'void Pipeline<T>::Register(IOperation<T>&) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
G:\Projects\Cpp Practice\Pipeline\main.cpp:59:19:   required from here
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:90:56: error: static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from input type
   90 |       static_assert(is_constructible<_ValueType, _Tp>::value,
      |                                                        ^~~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:90:56: note: 'std::integral_constant<bool, false>::value' evaluates to false
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of 'constexpr void std::_Construct(_Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Args = {IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > >}]':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:120:21:   required from 'constexpr _ForwardIterator std::__do_uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = move_iterator<IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*>; _ForwardIterator = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:370:30:   required from 'constexpr _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = move_iterator<IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*>; _ForwardIterator = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*; _Tp = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:397:2:   required from 'constexpr _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Allocator&) [with _InputIterator = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*; _ForwardIterator = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*; _Allocator = allocator<IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/vector.tcc:487:3:   required from 'constexpr void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_realloc_insert(iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&}; _Tp = IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; iterator = std::vector<IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >::iterator]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1287:21:   required from 'constexpr void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; value_type = IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]'
G:\Projects\Cpp Practice\Pipeline\main.cpp:35:33:   required from 'void Pipeline<T>::Register(IOperation<T>&) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
G:\Projects\Cpp Practice\Pipeline\main.cpp:59:19:   required from here
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_construct.h:115:28: error: no matching function for call to 'construct_at(IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*&, IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >)'
  115 |           std::construct_at(__p, std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_construct.h:94:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp, class ... _Args> constexpr decltype (::new(void*(0)) _Tp) std::construct_at(_Tp*, _Args&& ...)'
   94 |     construct_at(_Tp* __location, _Args&&... __args)
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_construct.h:94:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_construct.h: In substitution of 'template<class _Tp, class ... _Args> constexpr decltype (::new(void*(0)) _Tp) std::construct_at(_Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Args = {IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >}]':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_construct.h:115:21:   required from 'constexpr void std::_Construct(_Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Args = {IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > >}]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:120:21:   required from 'constexpr _ForwardIterator std::__do_uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = move_iterator<IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*>; _ForwardIterator = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:370:30:   required from 'constexpr _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = move_iterator<IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*>; _ForwardIterator = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*; _Tp = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:397:2:   required from 'constexpr _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Allocator&) [with _InputIterator = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*; _ForwardIterator = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*; _Allocator = allocator<IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/vector.tcc:487:3:   required from 'constexpr void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_realloc_insert(iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&}; _Tp = IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; iterator = std::vector<IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >::iterator]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1287:21:   required from 'constexpr void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; value_type = IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]'
G:\Projects\Cpp Practice\Pipeline\main.cpp:35:33:   required from 'void Pipeline<T>::Register(IOperation<T>&) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
G:\Projects\Cpp Practice\Pipeline\main.cpp:59:19:   required from here
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_construct.h:96:17: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >'
   96 |     -> decltype(::new((void*)0) _Tp(std::declval<_Args>()...))
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of 'constexpr void std::_Construct(_Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Args = {IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > >}]':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:120:21:   required from 'constexpr _ForwardIterator std::__do_uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = move_iterator<IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*>; _ForwardIterator = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:370:30:   required from 'constexpr _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = move_iterator<IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*>; _ForwardIterator = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*; _Tp = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:397:2:   required from 'constexpr _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Allocator&) [with _InputIterator = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*; _ForwardIterator = IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*; _Allocator = allocator<IOperation<__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/vector.tcc:487:3:   required from 'constexpr void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_realloc_insert(iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&}; _Tp = IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; iterator = std::vector<IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >::iterator]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1287:21:   required from 'constexpr void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; value_type = IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]'
G:\Projects\Cpp Practice\Pipeline\main.cpp:35:33:   required from 'void Pipeline<T>::Register(IOperation<T>&) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
G:\Projects\Cpp Practice\Pipeline\main.cpp:59:19:   required from here
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_construct.h:119:7: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >'
  119 |       ::new((void*)__p) _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Comment: You should post the complete error that you're getting in your question.

Comment: `std::vector<IOperation<T>> operations{};` - you cannot have a vector of abstract types. You need to store either pointers or `std::reference_wrapper`s in the vector instead

Comment: Can you please tell me the syntax for both reference & pointers here ?

Comment: @UnholySheep changed to `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<IOperation<T>>> operations{};` . Getting error as : `error: 'class std::reference_wrapper<IOperation<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >' has no member named 'Invoke'
   44 |                 operation.Invoke(data); `

Comment: You'd need to either replace `for (auto& operation : operations)` with `for (IOperation<T>& operation : operations)` or use `operation.get().Inokve(data);` in the loop body.

Comment: @UnholySheep Works perfectly with both reference & pointers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**as @UnholySheep mentioned, having a vector of classes that contain a base class type will not let you add sub extended classes to it.** When this happens, the sub class is basically converted back into its inherited class, and loses the virtual function `Invoke()`.

So when you call Invoke, it will always call the super's version of the virtual function.

one way to get around this is to store pointers or references in the vector as these keep the sub class type info as all you are storing is a pointer or reference TO your object. In this case, using a std::shared_ptr or std::unique_ptr will work.

try changing your pipeline class to:

```
template<typename T>
   class Pipeline : public IOperation<T>
    {
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IOperation<T>>> operations{}; 
       
       public:
       Pipeline(){}
        // add operation at the end of the pipeline
        void Register(std::shared_ptr<IOperation<T>> operation)
        {
            operations.push_back(operation);
        }

        // invoke every operations
        void Invoke(T data) override
        {
            
            for (auto& operation : operations)
            {
                operation->Invoke(data);
                
            }
                        
            
        }
    };
```

... and then your main() to:

```
int main(){

std::shared_ptr<ReverseStringOperation<std::string>> rObj = std::make_shared<ReverseStringOperation<std::string>>();
std::string str = "Hello";

Pipeline<std::string> *pipeline = new Pipeline<std::string>();

pipeline->Register(rObj);
//pipeline->Invoke(str);
    
    delete pipeline;
    return 0;
}
```

and see if it works.